# printing 1 row session values in different rows

Tags: php, session

**book.php:**

```
<td height="45" >Your Selected Seat(s) : 
      <input type="text" id="total_seats" name="total_seats" value="" readonly /></td>
```

**view.php:**

```
<td><?php echo $_SESSION['total_seats'];?></td>
```

Here my seat number are displaying like 1,2,3 but i want to display them in different rows but when i used array and foreach its showing me invalid arguement ..

Comment: try `explode($_SESSION['total_seats'], ',')` to get array of the seats. Then foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were probably trying to do `foreach` on the `$_SESSION['total_seats']` which is a string. You have to *explode* it to an array:

```
$seats = explode(',', $_SESSION['total_seats']);
foreach ($seats as $seat) {
    echo $seat . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: If you want the HTML output to be shown in different rows, see my edit.

Comment: i did the same n it's fixed :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143498/how-to-get-serial-numbers-dynamically   .. have a look please