# How to get serial numbers dynamically?

Tags: php

I want to get serial number 1 to any number dynamically, when my values fetched and show in a table. I ve used  but no result, I want the numbers according to my inserted values, if i m getting 3 rows i want  1 2 3 .

here 1st one is my result table

[image: here my tables]

but I want like this

[image: but i want like this]

the numbers should dispalye according to my entry dynamically

**table code**

```
    <td><span class="style2">Sl. No.</span></td>
    <td><span class="style2">Seat No.</span></td>
    <td><span class="style2">Passenger Name</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><ol type="1">1</ol></td>
    <td>
    <?php
        $seats = explode(',', $_SESSION['total_seats']);
        foreach ($seats as $seat) {
            echo $seat . "<br><br>";
        }
    ?> </td>
    <td>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['chksbmt'])){
            $counts = count($_SESSION['seat']);
            for($i=1;$i<=$counts;$i++){
                echo "<input type='text' name='passenger_name[]' style='border:1px solid #000;' required /><br/><br/>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td>
```

Comment: could you please paste some code here??

Comment: Should every `$seat` be in separate row? Also, I'd like to know what is the `$_SESSION['seat']` variable. Should it be `$_SESSION['total_seats']`?

Comment: yeah.. but i want to create the serial numbers dynamically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remember to increase the number for each row.

```
<?php
    $serial_no = 1;
    foreach ($seats as $seat) {
?>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <?php echo $serial_no++; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
         other markup here
      </td>
<tr>
<?php   } ?>
```

Comment: What is this?? I don't understand your solution at all.

Comment: me too .. i want serial numbers

Comment: Seriously? This is correct. Remember to put a single <input> in the loop. In other words, don't do another foreach in the <td> section.

Comment: This code is running fine .. but its giving my one extra serial number with one extra each field i want to display

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the whole row in the loop. Try this:

```
    <td><span class="style2">Sl. No.</span></td>
    <td><span class="style2">Seat No.</span></td>
    <td><span class="style2">Passenger Name</span></td>
</tr> 
    <?php
    $seats = explode(',', $_SESSION['total_seats']);
    foreach ($seats as $i => $seat) {
        echo '<tr>'.
                '<td>' . ($i+1) . '</td>'.
                '<td>'. $seat . '</td>'.
                '<td><input type="text" name="passenger_name[]" style="border:1px solid #000;" required /></td>'.
            '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: i ve more columns here

Comment: i have more codes to execute there

Comment: I forgot to add `tr` to the loop. I updated the answer.

Comment: your code works perfect but if i m checking 3 checkboxes from my prev page its giving me 4 text fields. n i think that's bcz of that $i+1, how can i match them ??

Comment: The number of text fields (and rows, generally) depends on number of elements in `$_SESSION['total_seats']` array. Keys in array starts from `0` but you want them to start from `1`. That's why I used `$i+1`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you does not rend the form each row per seat.
Also I don't know what does $_SESSION['total_seats'] contains.
But you can try this.

```
<?php 
$rowNo = 1;
foreach(explode(',', $_SESSION['total_seats']) as $seatNo){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$rowNo?></td>
        <td><?=$seatNo?></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='passenger_name[]' style='border:1px solid #000;' required /><br/><br/></td>
    </tr>
    <?
    $rowNo++;
}?>
```

Comment: $_SESSION['total_seats'] contains the seat numbers checked from check boxes in the prev page

Comment: it's giving me the perfect results but this 1 hampering my prev codes.. :(

Comment: The use $rowNo = $_GET['count'], assuming your page was called for example mydomain.com/mypage.php?count=3

Comment: i m just displaying with count .. m not calling my page with that...

Comment: ur code works perfect , but 1 problem if i m checking 3 seats from the previous page its showing 4 texboxes along upto serial no 4

Comment: Modify your question, attach the content of the all $_SESSION in var_dump / print_r format.

Comment: Ur code working perfectly but 1 problem is when m selecting 3 check boxes from the previous page to open dynamically text fields its giving me 5 text fields, i mean 1 more ...